# Check if an item exists in different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I check if an item exists in different fields in a document?

I currently have the below :

```
Room.findOne({
  editUrl: req.params.roomName
}, function(err, room) {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
 }
```

I want to also check if *req.params.roomName* exists in the field viewUrl.
What is the way to do this without having to do another findOne().

EDIT :
using the $or operator I can check if an item is in field 1 or field 2. What I need now is how do I add a condition if the item i am searching for is in field 1 and another condition if it is in field 2

EDIT 2: Please find below my original function: What this was doing is first check if the parameter exist. If it exists then update that document and add the user in the users array. Now what I need is to check if the parameter exists in either the editUrl field or in the viewUrl field. If it exists in the editUrl field then add the user to the *users* array else if it exists in the viewUrl field, then add the user to the *viewOnlyUsers* array.

```
Room.findOne({
  editUrl: req.params.roomName
}, function(err, room) {
   if (err) {
     return err;
   }
   if (room != null) {
     Room.update({
       editUrl: req.params.roomName
   }, {
     $addToSet: {
       users: req.user._id
  }
   }, function(err,
  count) {
  if (!count) {
    return err
  }
});
res.render('account/board');
} else {
res.sendStatus(404);
}
});
```

Comment: You could use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or).

Comment: Thanks for the $or operator. This works but now I want do some action based on if it matches  the first field and another action if it matches the second field. Is this possible?

Comment: just to be clear, can you edit your question to show what operations you would like to do based on what conditions. I think you are looking for a solution beyond the capability of a find query offered by the aggregation framework.

Comment: you can put a check on the response (room) of the findOne function

Comment: EDIT 2 explains in detail what i need with piece of my actual code

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the $or operator

```
Room.findOne({
$or:[{editUrl: req.params.roomName},{viewUrl: req.params.roomName}]
}, function(err, room) {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
 }
```

Documentation of $or operator https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/